# Why does getEventById() return null?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

So I'm pretty new to coding with GAS and I've been working on this the other day. The idea is to have a spreadsheet of events and create them in my calendar and check if the event already exists and update it if there are any changes to the name or date of the event.

Here's my code for reference:

```
function events() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("test");
  const cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calID");

  for (i = 3; i <= sheet.getLastRow(); i++) {
    var date = sheet.getRange(i, 8).getValue();

    if (date > 0) {
      var title = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
      var id = sheet.getRange(i, 9).getValue();

      if (id != 0) {
        var ide = cal.getEventById("id");
        var idf = ide.getAllDayStartDate();
        var idn = ide.getTitle();

        if (date != idf) {
          ide.setAllDayDate(fecha);
        }
        if (title != idn) {
          ide.setTitle(nombre);
        }
      }
      else {
        var nid = cal.createAllDayEvent(name, date).getId();
        sheet.getRange(i, 9).setValue(nid);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I was able to create the events succesfully but when it checks the date of an already existing one it says this:

```
Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAllDayStartDate' of null
```

Later, using the Logger.log() I found out that this is returning as null even tho the event with that ID exists and it has access to the calendar:

```
var ide = cal.getEventById("id");
```

I then looked online and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60494042/apps-script-geteventbyid-returns-null#60619676) but when i tried running the code marked as a solution this returns empty:

```
var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEvents(now, nextEvent);
```

I then tried deleting and allowing again the permissions for calendar and sheets but it didn't work.
I even tried editing the appsscript.json file by hand like this:

```
{
  ...
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly",
    "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
  ]
  ...
}
```

But that didn't work either.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit:

I've now tested with the default calendar and creating a new calendar but it doesn't work. I'm starting to think it's a bug but I'm not sure what could be causing it.

Comment: well, there are no miracles: there is no such event in your calendar

Comment: Thanks for the response @Kos. There is, in fact, an event with that ID. I can see the event in my calendar and checked both the calendar ID and event ID, and they both match. So idk why I can't access the event by ID, or any event whatsoever. Maybe it's a config issue?

Comment: and how do you see event id in your calendar? it's impossible

Comment: I followed this tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755413/how-can-i-find-the-event-id-of-my-google-calendar-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was writting `getEventById("id")` and it should've been `getEventById(id)`:

```
...
      var id = sheet.getRange(i, 9).getValue();

      if (id != 0) {
        var ide = cal.getEventById(id);
...
```